# Append html tag to table header Jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have this kind of TR structure, what i need is with juqey to add some image beside the link here is structure i have

```
<tr>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">One</a></th>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">Two</a></th>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">Three</a></th>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">Four</a></th>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">Five</a></th>
  <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">Six</a></th>
</tr>
```

What i need is inside a href add some hmtl tag like this

```
 <th  class="k-header" data-role="sortable"><a href="#" class="k-link">One <p>New link</p></a></th>
```

I have some data attribute that i can get all element, but how to add some new tag inside that, all tables are going from ajax, and that is another thing that i think of, maybe some on() or live()

Any idea?
This is what i have for now :)

```
$(function() {
    var target = $('[data-role~=sortable]');


    target.live(function() {


    });
});
```

Comment: I recommend stepping back from your current task and taking an hour or two to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It really only takes that long, and gives you the answers to all sorts of questions like this.

Comment: This what you saind is ok, with append, but the problem is that is ajax call??

Comment: Ajax calls have completion callbacks.

Comment: Yesok, but i have so many ajax calls, i dont want to mess the code, only i need something common

Comment: Ah, okay -- there's something for that, too, I've posted a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you have to use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** in jquery

```
 $(".k-link").append("<p>New link</p>");
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that table goes from ajax?

Comment: @Gorostas you can call this method after Ajax call completed ( success )

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the question:

> Yesok, but i have so many ajax calls, i dont want to mess the code, only i need something common

You're looking for [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), which lets you specify a callback which gets called for **any** succesful jQuery ajax call.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $(".k-link").append("<p>New link</p>");
});
```

or if for some reason you can't use `.k-link` (since you didn't in your question):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $("[data-role~=sortable] a").append("<p>New link</p>");
});
```

Note the `a` in the selector, to get to the anchor. Note that I'm assuming you used `~=` rather than `=` on purpose, that `data-role` may have a series of space-separated values, like `class` does.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example, you can see it in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/d2gdpu96/2/

to access to the data inside the `<a>` you can use following code:

```
$("tr th a").each(function(){
    //whatever you want to do with each <a>
    var CurrentATag=$(this);
    var ATagInnerHTML=CurrentATag.html();
});
```

if you want to select more precisely, just a specific table with id, you can use following code:

```
$("#tabelID tr th a").each(function(){
   //your code here;
});
```